# GridView 3x3 screen size independent

Tags: android, layout, gridview

I would like to make a GridView with fixed columns and rows 3x3. Everything goes right but the problem is that the grid get vertical scroll on 3" screen and empty space on bottom in a 5" screen.

Is it possible to make it have no scroll independent on the screen size? Besides is the GridView the best option for it?

Comment: Why not using 4 LinearLayouts? First with vertical orientaion and 3 LinearLayout childs with horizontal orientaion. And set `layout_weight` to 1 in them

Comment: Sounds good. I'll try it and post the result. Thank you.